# Tricky GROUP BY SQL with additional constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a "members" table like this:

```
id   status    user_id   created_at
-----------------------------------
1    active    1         2015-07-01
2    active    2         2015-07-01
3    inactive  1         2015-07-04
4    deleted   2         2015-07-04
5    active    3         2015-07-04
6    active    1         2015-07-08
7    inactive  3         2015-07-08
```

How is it possible to query the latest status of all users at any given date?

For **2015-07-01** the output should be:

```
id   status    user_id   created_at
-----------------------------------
1    active    1         2015-07-01
2    active    2         2015-07-01
```

For **2015-07-05** the output should be:

```
id   status    user_id   created_at
-----------------------------------
3    inactive  1         2015-07-04
4    deleted   2         2015-07-04
5    active    3         2015-07-04
```

For **2015-07-10** the output should be:

```
id   status    user_id   created_at
-----------------------------------
3    active    1         2015-07-08
4    deleted   2         2015-07-04
5    inactive  3         2015-07-08
```

Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `group by` with `where` to get the latest date before the given date, then a join:

```
select m.*
from members m join
     (select user_id, max(created_at) as maxca
      from members
      where created_at <= '2015-07-08'  -- or whatever
      group by user_id
     ) mu
     on m.user_id = mu.user_id and m.created_at = mu.maxca;
```

Comment: this only returns one row, not a row for every user_id

Comment: @santacruz . . . This should return a row for every user id.  Set up a SQL Fiddle, so I can see what you are doing.